# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch hides content on scroll with safari

Tags: ios, css, scroll, webkit, mobile-safari

I have a multi page site that is fully functional on any device except for iphone and ipad. Scrolling is choppy and not smooth and momentum scrolling seems like it's only possible if I apply these styles to the body:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

but after I apply those styles, content disappears and gets hidden after scrolling by it. I saw others solved this by adding the content to memory with the use of this trick:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

but that had no success for me.

Is there an alternative to using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to achieve the momentum scrolling effect on ios? Or any other fixes that I could try?

Any suggestions are welcome!

UPDATE!!

I solved it!
I ended up applying this style

```
*:not(html) {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

There were a few elements that I was using the transform property on already, so i had to go in and adjust those individually. Feels dirty but it works